# How to disable new window on submit mailchimp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm looking for a solution or actually is there any code that would disable the opening of a new window/tab using Mailchimp form?

I've got javascript and php taking care of the "thank you" div that is shown and the form div being hidden upon submit... however, it still processes the New Window / Tab function as well.

Any easy way to stop that from happening?

Comment: From the form you'll get from mailchimp, look for the **target="_blank"** and replace it with the **target="_self"**

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `<form method="post" ...` from mailchimp, you can replicate the request using jQuery or javascript.

So if the mailchimp form is:

```
<form method="post" action="http://mailchimp.com/a/3asfha/nsdf">
  <input type="text" name="mailchimp-name" id="name"></input>
  <input type="text" name="mailchimp-email" id="email"></input>
</form>
```

Instead, you'd do something like this:

```
 $("form").submit(function (e) {
   $.post('http://mailchimp.com/a/3asfha/nsdf', {
      mailchimp-name: $("#name").val(),
      mailchimp-email: $("#email").val()
   }).success(function (data) {
    // do stuff on return
   });
   e.preventDefault()
 });
```

Something in this pattern should send the form data to mailchimp without opening a new tab.

Comment: I see what you are doing.. now how would you possibly also do handle for errors? `like }).error(function (data)` {?? I'm only asking because the above doesn't seem to send anything.

Comment: also isn't the end missing a `});' ??

Comment: Yeah, you're right, you'd do the same for errors.. and its missing a );, good catch.

Comment: btw, its possible you will need to tweak this for your use case (i.e., is the method still post? are you seeing any console errors?)